# TableView of products ID disappeared with iOS 7 in Xcode 5

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5, tableview

Yesterday I could test my app on iOS Simulator [iOS 6.x]: everything worked fine.

Today I installed Xcode 5 and tried testing the app after changing iOS Deployment Target to 7.0: when I hit Run in the Simulator the app starts and shows me any static item/cell, but prototyped cells for my product Ids available through InAppPurchase are disappeared!

In the debug area I get the string "Failed to load list of products." which is the message I set into the didFailWithError of the SKRequest.

This error should be surely connected to the update of the SDK, I'd guess... any idea about the solution of that?

Simulator info: Version 7.0 (463.9.4).

I' can't explain, instead, my joy when I tried running the app into the iPhone 5 actual device and everything worked fine, as expected...wow.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to debug inAppPurchase Ina simulator?

Comment: Yes, I did it before with iOS 6.x simulator. You can do almost anything, except download hosted content if I'm right.

Comment: THe console prints out the following message: 2013-09-27 15:08:36.981 In App Rage[622:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xa5944d0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/StoreKitFramework.axbundle> (not loaded). It confirms the problem in inside the simulator... I suppose..

Comment: OK, Apple knows the problem, as written here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241. "StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338"

Answer (score 0):

OK, Apple knows the problem, as written here: developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/….

"StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338"